# Is there a way to select a specific element with a class?

Tags: css

I have a need to apply a specific style only to a specific instance of the class.

So...let's say I have the following in my html:

```
<div class="dog">Text</div>
<div class="dog">More text</div>
<div class="dog">Even more text</div>
```

Is there a selector or something I can use to apply a slight variation to the second div with the "dog" class but not the other two divs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You could use `:nth-child()` selector.

```css
.dog:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="dog">Text</div>
<div class="dog">More text</div>
<div class="dog">Even more text</div>
```

---

If you want to select all `div`s with class `.dog`, but first and last `div`s you could combine `:not()`, `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type` selectors(`.dog:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type)`).

```css
.dog:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="dog">Text</div>
<div class="dog">More text</div>
<div class="dog">Even more text</div>
<div class="dog">Text</div>
<div class="dog">More text</div>
<div class="dog">Even more text</div>
<div class="dog">Text</div>
<div class="dog">More text</div>
<div class="dog">Even more text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add a second class like this `<div class="dog second">More text</div>` 
your css is for example `div.dog.second {color:red;}`

Comment: Should be `div.dog.second`

Answer (score 1):

you may use eq selector from jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

If you want to avoid jQuery and javascript you may take a look into :nth-child() pseudo-selector, but is CSS3, and CSS3 is not supported in old browsers.

Comment: There is no need for jQuery here.

Comment: However you can use the second solution: CSS3

Answer (score 1):

If you give one element an id and then specify it in your style sheet it should work.

```
<div class="dog" id="altered"/>
```